# Filter rows where the lead/lag are specific values (window with filter)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a data frame like this:

```
  id x y
1  a 1 P
2  a 2 S
3  b 3 P
4  b 4 S
```

I want to keep rows where the 'lead' value of y is 'S' let us say, so that my resulting data frame will be:

```
      id     x      y
1      a     1      P
2      b     3      P
```

I am able to do it as follows with PySpark:

```py
getLeadPoint = udf(lambda x: 'S' if (y == 'S') else 'NOTS', StringType())
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(df['id'])
df = df.withColumn('lead_point', getLeadPoint(lead(df.y).over(windowSpec)))
dfNew = df.filter(df.lead_point == 'S')
```

But, here, I am mutating an unnecessary column and then filtering.

What I want to do instead is something like this where I filter using lead(), but can't get it to work:

```py
dfNew = df.filter(lead(df.y).over(windowSpec) == 'S')
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve the result with direct filter using windowing?

R equivalent is:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(lead(y) == 'S')
```

Comment: Sorry....BTW - the ordering part is a place holder. There is a 'timestamp' column in my data that I need to order by.

Comment: There is actually a bug here.  The simplest workaround is just to add a column using `withColumn` and use it for filtering.

Comment: Thank you for verifying. So, my current solution is the best I can do?

Comment: You don't need the `udf` here, you can just filter the output of `lead()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("a", 1,  1, "P"), ("a", 2,  2, "S"),
    ("b", 4,  2, "S"), ("b", 3,  1, "P"), ("b", 2,  3, "P"), ("b", 3,  3, "S")
]).toDF(["id", "x", "timestamp", "y"])
```

and window spec is equivalent to

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead, col
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")
```

you can simply add column and use it for filtering:

```
(df
    .withColumn("lead_y", lead("y").over(w))
    .where(col("lead_y") == "S").drop("lead_y"))
```

It is not pretty but will be way more efficient than UDF call.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient, but you can zip with index, then make a new RDD where you add 1 to the index, then join on the index and then it turns into a simple filter operation.

Comment: Thanks! That I think is a worse solution than me mutating a new column of lead values, as I am currently doing. Also, without code, it is hard to say what your solution actually looks like or does.